# Create new Database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a new database using mongo.
(not a collection in the current database like the result of use "newDBname" )
Does anyone know how to do so?

An example in c# would be appreciated.

have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/#create-a-database), there is no such explicit operation/query, the database will be created implicitly when you will first time query to it if it wasn't created before. In c# it will be:

```
 var database = client.GetDatabase("db_name");  // on this step, the server doesn't know that you want to create db_name
 database.ListCollections(null, CancellationToken.None); // the database will be created only after running query, for example "ListCollections"
```

Comment: You're right this is the correct way to do it. Additional in my case the actual problem was that I did it async way and I inserted the data before the new db created

Answer (score 0):

With mongoose ? If you're using mongoose, create a new schema for new collection.

After launch your backend, the new collection should be create.